# PHP Multiple form in same page

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm doing form in php but I have some problem.
First I will have 3 different form in the same page.
What I want is only 1 form appear and then with the answer a second form will appear and so on.
The answer of the form will be display on the same page.
For now my first form work and after get the answer go to the 2nd form but I want to submit the 2nd form the problem appear.
It delete the answer of my first form and don't do anything (everything start like I am in my first form).
I try to find the problem but can't have idea about how to solve it.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">  
    Q1?
    <input type="number" name="nbtemplate" min="1" max="30">
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutton1" value="Confirm!">
</form>

<?php 
if(!isset($submitbutton1)) {  
    if (!empty($_POST['nbtemplate']) != "") { 
        echo "<b>{$_POST['nbtemplate']}</b> !\n";
        echo "<br />";
        $Nnbtemplate = $_POST['nbtemplate'];
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE tb SET day='$Nnbtemplate'") or die(mysql_error()); 
?>  

<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>' method='post'>   
Q2? <br>            
<?php 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $Nnbtemplate; $i++) { // start loop 
        echo "Template ";
        echo $i;
?>      

<input type="number" name="nbtime" min="1" max="96"> 

<?php 
}   
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submitbutton2" value="Confirm!">';
    echo '</form>';

    if(isset($submitbutton1) && !isset($submitbutton2)) {
    if (!empty($_POST['nbtime']) != "") {
    echo "<b>{$_POST['nbtime']}</b> !\n";
    echo "<br />";
    $nbtime = $_POST['nbtime'];

    for ($j = 1; $j <= $nbtime; $j++) {
    echo "Time";
    echo $j;
?>
    Q3:
    <input type="time" name="starttime"> To <input type="time" name="endtime"> 

<?php
    }
    echo '<input type="submit">';
    echo '</form>';
        }

    }       
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: that's some ugly code you got there

Comment: dude you should close `}` your code before you close the php tag `?>`

Comment: the variable $submitbutton1 is not defined in your code. Have You used extract($_POST) ?

Answer (score 0):

That is some gnarly code you got there, brother. This is a really simple task when handled with some javascript. Then you can have a single post to your php. I like using the jQuery framework so here's a couple links I found quickly: [this one](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/turn-any-webform-into-a-powerful-wizard-with-jquery-formtowizard-plugin/) and [this one](http://webexpedition18.com/articles/how-to-create-a-multi-step-signup-form-with-css3-and-jquery/)

Example code in response to comment about building form elements dynamically:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- load jquery library -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="toyourpage.php">

    How Many?:
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
    <div id="add"></div>

</form>

<!-- javascript go -->
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input#number').keyup(function()
    {   
        var num = $(this).val(); // get num

        if(!isNaN(num)) // check if number
        {
            $('div#add').html(''); // empty
            for(i = 1; i <= num; i++) // add
            {
                $('div#add').append('New Field ' + i + ': <input type="text" name="next_' + i + '" id="next' + i + '"><br>');
                }
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Valid number required');
        }

    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks it looks like what i want, I just have one question. is it possible with this to take the value of the 1st step (like ask a number) and on second step, repeat the form as much as the number in 1st step?

Comment: Sure. I'll add an example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes on Your code, and have tested, it works.

You had any mistakes in your `{}` brackets and `if` conditions. Also as I commented I added `extract($_POST)`.

```
<?php
extract ( $_POST );
if (! isset ( $submitbutton1 ) && !isset($submitbutton2)) {
    ?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
    Q1? <input type="number" name="nbtemplate" min="1" max="30"> <input
        type="submit" name="submitbutton1" value="Confirm!">
</form>
<?php ;
}
if (isset ( $submitbutton1 )) {
    if (! empty ( $_POST ['nbtemplate'] ) != "") {
        echo "<b>{$_POST['nbtemplate']}</b> !\n";
        echo "<br />";
        $Nnbtemplate = $_POST ['nbtemplate'];
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE tb SET day='$Nnbtemplate'") or
        die(mysql_error());
        ?>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>' method='post'>
    Q2? <br>            
<?php
        for($i = 1; $i <= $Nnbtemplate; $i ++) { // start loop
            echo "Template ";
            echo $i;
            ?>      
<input type="number" name="nbtime" min="1" max="96"> 
<?php
        }
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submitbutton2" value="Confirm!">';
        echo '</form>';
    }   
}   
        if ( isset ( $submitbutton2 )) {
            if (! empty ( $_POST ['nbtime'] ) != "") {
                echo "<b>{$_POST['nbtime']}</b> !\n";
                echo "<br />";
                $nbtime = $_POST ['nbtime'];
                for($j = 1; $j <= $nbtime; $j ++) {
                    echo "Time";
                    echo $j;
                    ?>
    Q3:
    <input type="time" name="starttime"> To <input type="time"
        name="endtime"> 

<?php
                }
                echo '<input type="submit">';
                echo '</form>';
            }

        }
?>
```